# Load Url in Web View Intel Xdk

Tags: intel-xdk

I want to convert my website to mobile application with Intel XDK. So , how to do this with web view.I want to load the URL on the current web view not open it on a new page with the native browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy way is to use `window.location=` to load URL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.location = "http://www.yourwebsite.com";
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Better way is to use `InAppBrowser` and `connection` Cordova plugins to load website, so that you can handle connection loss and reload, it will load complete website in background and then display, here is code: https://github.com/krisrak/html5-cordova-webapp